# Proving that for any odd integer:$\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \right\rfloor = \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{4}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that for any odd integer, the floor of:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \right\rfloor = \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{4}$$

Any help is appreciated to construct this proof!

Thanks guys.

Comment: OP: You might want to stop systematically defacing your questions, the fact has been signalled to the moderators and may result in your suspension.

Answer (score 7):

Let $n$ be an odd integer.

Then there exists an integer $k$, such that:
$$n=2k+1$$

It follows that:
$$\begin{align}
\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{(4k^2+4k+1)}{4}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{(4k^2+4k)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor(k^2+k)+\frac{1}{4}\right\rfloor
\end{align}
$$

Because $k^2+k$ is an integer, we can now say:
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor = k^2+k$$

It also follows that:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{4} &= \frac{n^2-1}{4}\\
&= \frac{(2n+1)^2-1}{4}\\
&= \frac{(4k^2+4k+1)-1}{4}\\
&= \frac{4k^2+4k}{4}\\
&= k^2+k\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore:
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor=\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{4}$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3):

Take $n=2k+1$ then,

$\lfloor(n^2/4)\rfloor=\lfloor k^2+k+1/4\rfloor=k^2+k$

$\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{4}=(n^2-1)/4=k^2+k=\lfloor(n^2/4)\rfloor$